# Magento 2 graphql integration with Amazon Pay

Tags: magento2.4, graphql, integration, amazon

I am trying to implement payment for Amazon Pay in Magento 2.4 using graphql. Magento documentation provides steps for Pay Pal (e.g. PayPal Express Checkout: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/payment-methods/paypal-express-checkout.html). For Pay Pal works. How to implement this for Amazon Pay?

When I try to call

```
mutation {
  setPaymentMethodOnCart(input: {
cart_id: "EUZwlk3kflddMgPoGe6KVDjcWm5CEgid"
    payment_method: {
      code: "amazon_payment"
    }
  }) {
    cart {
    selected_payment_method {
        code
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then I get the error:

```
[2020-10-15 11:31:46] main.ERROR: Call to a member function getAmazonOrderReferenceId() on null {"exception":"[object] (GraphQL\\Error\\Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getAmazonOrderReferenceId() on null at /var/www/magento2/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Error/Error.php:174, Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getAmazonOrderReferenceId() on null at /var/www/magento2/vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/Plugin/ConfirmOrderReference.php:109)"} []
```

Comment: I have developed amazonpay graphql module. [Check it here](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/GraphQl/Amazonpay)